# Xamarin RelayCommand doesn't work

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

I have a simple code using `RelayCommand` of MVVM Light nuget but is not working, just want to push a button and display a message,

My xaml code:

```
 <StackLayout
  Padding="8">
    <Button

        Command="{Binding ConvertCommand}"

        Text="Hello">
    </Button>
</StackLayout>
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ICommand ConvertCommand { get { return new RelayCommand(ConvertMoney); } }

    public async void ConvertMoney()
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("hello", "hello", "acept");
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you set the binding context of your view? Also don't use async with void, use a Task instead.

Comment: The binding works fine, using Command instead RelayCommand worked very well, thank you for your comments!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing setting the `BindingContext` of your `Page` or `StackLayout` to your `ViewModel`.

For example

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:MainViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

or

```
<StackLayout.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:MainViewModel/>
</StackLayout.BindingContext>
```

By the way you don't need to add `MvvmLight` to your `Xamarin.Forms` project, because `Xamarin.Forms` has it own implementation of `ICommand`. You can simply use `Command`.